# Can not access class in jar file on a web project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, vaadin

I created a jar file from a java project in Eclipse, this jar have a unique class and an int variable.

I imported the jar file in a web project (Vaadin project) that is deployed in .war file. But when I open the app in the browser it throws an java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

By the way I test it in a typical java project and it works the problem is on a web project (war file)

Below an image of the error. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Why do you have a jar in your src/main/java folder?

Comment: Because I copied it and did "add build to path" just because when I did "add external jar" it also doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the jar to the Deployment Assemblies, not only to the Build Path.